# Posterior predictive distribution(Bayes regression)

Tags: probability, bayesian, mathematical-statistics

Assume we have some  linear regression of the form
$$y^{(i)}=\theta^{T}x^{(i)}+e^{(i)}$$

where:
$$P(y^{(i)}|x^{(i)},\theta)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}exp(-\frac{(y^{(i)}-\theta^{T}x^{(i)})^{2}}{2\sigma^{2}})$$

Then using Bayes Rule we obtain some parameter distribution $p(\theta|S)$ where S is our dataset.

My problem is with derivation of **posterior predictive distribution** which is given in notes as follows:

Given new test point $x_{*}$ probability distribution over possible outputs(posterior predictive distribution) is:

$$p(y_{*}|x_{*},S)=\int_{\theta}p(y_{*}|x_{*},\theta)p(\theta|S)d\theta $$

And I dont fully understand why exactly we have $p(\theta|S)$ instead of $p(\theta)$ in above formula, because my reasoning is following:

$$p(y_{*}|x_{*},S)=\int_{\theta}p(y_{*}|x_{*},\theta,S)p(\theta)d\theta =
\int_{\theta}p(y_{*}|x_{*},\theta)p(\theta)d\theta $$
(By marginal probability and independence of $x_{*}$ from  $S$)

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1993348/376402 here is also derivation of probability

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to condition on $S$ *everywhere* including in $\theta$ to take into account the information contained in $S$. By the marginalisation argument:
$$p(y_*|x_*,S)=\int p(y_*,\theta|x_*,S)\text{d}\theta=\int p(y_*|x_*,S,\theta)p(\theta|S,x_{*})\text{d}\theta=\int p(y_*|x_*,S,\theta)p(\theta|S)\text{d}\theta$$

Comment: I have still one question: why $p(y_{*}|x_{*},S,\theta)=p(y_{*}|x_{*}$,\theta)? http://cs229.stanford.edu/section/cs229-gaussian_processes.pdf page 4.  On the one hand the formula (3) on page 4 suggest that $p(y_{*}|x_{*},\theta)$ is conditionally independent from S, on the other hand in the last formula on page 4 we see that distribution of $y_{*}$ is determined by $X$. You included S in final formula($p(y_{*}|x_{*},S,\theta)$. So what is the final answer: $p(y_*|x_*,S)=\int p(y_*|x_*,S,\theta)p(\theta|S)\text{d}\theta$ or $p(y_*|x_*,S)=\int p(y_*|x_*,\theta)p(\theta|S)\text{d}\theta$

Comment: In some settings like iid observations, $y_*$ is independent of the sample $S$ given the parameter $\theta$ and $x_*$. In others like time-series, there may be dependence on the current sample even given $\theta$ if you predict the next observation. (I did not include $S$ in the conditioning, [mokebe](http://stats.stackexchange.com/users/133995/mokebe) did. In doubt, you must keep the conditioning on $S$.